# unable to access sub-properties of an object.

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I have a javascript object set up somewhat like the following:

```
“someObject” : {
    “A” : { “id” : “323klj”, “name” : “subObject1”, “value” : “0” }
    “B” : { “id” : “63sdf”, “name” : “subObjectB”, “value” : “9” }
}
```

I am trying to access the “value” properties of the sub-objects.  However when I access them like so

```
console.log(someObject.A.value)
```

the result is undefined.

If I try outputting the following to the console just like this (one line after another)

```
console.log(someObject)
console.log(someObject.A) 
console.log(someObject.A.value)
```

In the console I will see the following:

-First Line:  someObject will be displayed as expected with all the sub-objects and properties intact

-Second Line: I will see the sub-object A, however the “value” property is missing

-Third Line: is undefined.

My question is does anybody have any ideas on what could possibly be making this happen?  I am having a hard time trouble shooting this problem and I don't understand how this is even possible.  I know that this should work under normal circumstances.  FYI: This is all part of a much larger backbone application where I am using jquery mobile as well.  Could it be something to do with one of these frameworks? (the actual code is too complex to paste here, I am just trying to give an example to illustrate what is going on).

Comment: How is the object generated? How are the properties set? Could it be that `value` is populated via Ajax and you are trying to access the property *before* it is set? Some consoles have a strange way of evaluating objects, so you should not trust every output.

Answer (score 2):

this works for me:

```
var someObject = {
    A : { id : "323klj", name : "subObject1", value : "0" },
    B : { id : "63sdf", name : "subObjectB", value : "9" }
}
console.log(someObject.A.value); //returns 0
console.log(someObject.B.value); //returns 9
```

note: copy-pasting your text I had to change the double-quotes, in my browser they were display as “ ” so I changed them to "

Comment: Thanks for checking it out w3jimmy, I was fairly confident that the code was valid, just something is wrong with my application.  The weird quotes were due to a text editor I made the wrote out the question in.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I ended up using a workaround, so I hate to have anyone else waist time on this one and will mark it as answered,  But still is quite puzzling to me what is going on...